# Spring Boot Library Dependency Management

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a maven multi module project used as internal library for our other spring boot apps. Like for example hashing password, uploading files to minio, query ldap etc.

We make use of existing spring boot stuff extensively in that multimodule project library.

This is an excerpt from the library's `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.thd</groupId>
    <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>email</module>
        <module>func</module>
        <module>geolocation</module>
        <module>hashing</module>
        <module>idm</module>
        <module>io</module>
        <module>ldap</module>
        <module>messaging</module>
        <module>minio</module>
    </modules>

     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies> <!-- The parent should provide all that -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I can include the module i need via pom in our other spring boot projects - for example:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.thd</groupId>
            <artifactId>ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${thd.utils.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now my questions:
**1. Is there a way to tell that library from its consuming app or better said from the outside of itself which spring boot version to use?**

In the multi module library i have the spring boot version hard coded:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**2. Is maven so smart to pull only the newer dependencies from spring boot? If my app uses spring boot 2.6.6 and the library is spring boot 2.6.4 for example do i end up with the jars from spring boot 2.6.6?**

**3. Is there a smarter way to architecture such a library?**

Answer (score 1):

In your outer project in your pom file when adding your dependency for your library add `<exclusions>` section in your `<dependency>` section for your library.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>de.thd</groupId>
            <artifactId>ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${thd.utils.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>                
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This will tell maven that when bringing your library do not bring alone its dependencies listed in `<exclusions>` section